# AWS: Secure API Gateway with developer authenticated identity

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I was wondering if anyone had a good idea around how to solve the following problem on API Gateway/Lambda - The consumers of the API simply need a token that will authorise them via a cognito authoriser attached to API gateway, the API must take care of everything and just fire back a token.

So a user sends my login Lambda their username and password so as per the docs I do the following(I chopped the error handling out for brevity):

```
    const cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity({ region: 'eu-west-1' })
    const userId = authenticationService.authorise(username, password)
    const params = {
        IdentityPoolId: 'eu-west-1:my-identity-pool-id',
        Logins: {
            'myapp.mydomain.com': userId,
        },
    }
    cognitoidentity.getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity(params, (err, data) => {

  // Now I have an OpenId token and an identity Id


})
```

Initially I thought I should then call GetCredentialsForIdentity but that doesn't return me the access token, am I heading down the correct route here or have I missed something?

Update: to be clear, I don't want consumers to have to implement the AWS client side sdk, basically I'd like them to simply be able to add a header that lets them make requests like a traditional api.

Comment: If the consumers don't need to implement AWS SDK, how do they get the token to access the API? You have a custom token generator or something similar to this for your consumers?

Comment: Well for user pools they get a JWT back which is fine - from further research I think Identity pools are a waste of time so yeah I'm thinking create your own JWT implementation for use with federated identities, I'll update this with an answer when I've proved it out.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Based on comment:
Check this code

```
 var data = {
        UserPoolId : '...', // Your user pool id here
        ClientId : '...' // Your client id here
    };
    var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(data);
    var cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();

    if (cognitoUser != null) {
        cognitoUser.getSession(function(err, session) {
            if (err) {
               alert(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log('session validity: ' + session.isValid());

            AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
                IdentityPoolId : '...' // your identity pool id here
                Logins : {
                    // Change the key below according to the specific region your user pool is in.
                    'cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<YOUR_USER_POOL_ID>' : session.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
                }
            });

            // Instantiate aws sdk service objects now that the credentials have been updated.
            // example: var s3 = new AWS.S3();

        });
    }
```

`session.getAccessToken().getJwtToken()` will give you accesstoken

This Link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html might help you.

You have to generate a access token after a user logs in using username and password. And you can verify that key later on. 
Else when user is verified you can generate a credential using STS and pass that.

For API gateway check if you can create API keys inside the code and use it.

Comment: Hey thanks for that, the problem I have is actually acquiring the access token, identity token etc once I have the openId token.

Comment: @MrkFldig Check the update.  Link : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html

Comment: Thanks Skarfa, but thats for a USER Pool, rather than an identity Pool.

Comment: @MrkFldig I think you can only get access/identity token from the user pool. 
check InitiateAuth function: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html

Comment: Yeah I've blinking at this ages, I can use assumeRoleWithWebIdentity but then the user needs to sign the requests themselves if they aren't using the aws sdk.

Answer (score 0):

The steps missing in the code are as follows:

- Call AWS STS to get temporary access tokens
- Sign the temporary access tokens
- Return this signed value and pass it, along with some other headers, in the final request.

The actual headers to pass in your request to the API endpoint are something like:

```
{
   'Authorization': 'algo Credentials=<creds>, SIgnedHeaders=host;x-amz-date, Signature=<sig>',
   'x-amz-date': '<some date>',
}
```

Actually creating those headers can be a bit of a pain.  The painful description can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html

I am using python on the backend, and I just used an AWS signing library to get that signature done for me.

https://gist.github.com/rcadena/e071c26d9e4126af42eb29182ca5acb1

Having said all that, I'm not sure if this whole way of providing signature for external clients is recommended.  Just to name one difficulty: if you have to pass a body to the the final endpoint request, then you have to get a totally new signature from your backend because the signature uses the body as part of its digest; you can't just reuse the Authorization header.

The next thing I'll investigate is maybe programmatically making API Gateway access tokens on the backend, but I'm not sure if these can be tied to an identity.